# Error applying CF13 on WebSphere Portal 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I'm here to ask about this error since it has been hours since i've started to solve it and I can't find anything on the web.
I've got a WebSphere Portal 8.5, fresh new installation.
I'm trying to install CF13: I've installed the binary correctly with the IM and launched applyCF, but it fails with this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- IBM WebSphere Portal/8.5 build 20161208-1058 exported on Fri Aug 04 10:08:55 CEST 2017 from itmi1lxp31.boltongroup.net/10.88.88.32 virtual portal: none (default virtual portal) -->
<request build="20161208-1058" type="update" version="8.5.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_8.5.0.xsd">
    <status element="[content-node Z6_00000000000000AU24LH4B1000 uniquename=ibm.portal.theme.simple.footer]" result="warning">
        <message id="EJPXA0060W">EJPXA0060W: A user or group with ID uid=wpsadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm could not be retrieved from the portal datastore, possibly because it does not exist. Related access-control configuration data will not be updated.</message>
    </status>
    <status element="[content-node Z6_00000000000000AU24LH4B1000 uniquename=ibm.portal.theme.simple.footer]" result="warning">
        <message id="EJPXA0060W">EJPXA0060W: A user or group with ID uid=wpsadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm could not be retrieved from the portal datastore, possibly because it does not exist. Related access-control configuration data will not be updated.</message>
    </status>
    <status element="[content-node Z6_00000000000000AU24LH4B1000 uniquename=ibm.portal.theme.simple.footer]" result="failed">
        <message id="EJPFB0002E">EJPFB0002E: Exception occurred.</message>
        <message id="EJPFB0002E">EJPFB0002E: Exception occurred.</message>
        <message>com.ibm.wps.util.DataBackendException: EJQHL0007E: An exception occurred when trying to modify the page data in Web Content Management for the page with the ID [ObjectIDImpl 'Z6_00000000000000AU24LH4B1000', CONTENT_NODE, VP: 0, [Domain: rel], DB: 0000-000000000000000080F282D448560000]. Detailed Message: EJPFB0007E: Exception occurred : IBM Web Content Manager is not available.</message>
        <stacktrace><![CDATA[
com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommandException: EJPFB0002E: Exception occurred. [content-node Z6_00000000000000AU24LH4B1000 uniquename=ibm.portal.theme.simple.footer]
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentMappingData.executeUnrestricted(ContentMappingData.java:631)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentMappingData.update(ContentMappingData.java:289)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentNodeItem.updateInternal(ContentNodeItem.java:1910)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentNodeItem.createInternal(ContentNodeItem.java:1397)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentNodeItem.create(ContentNodeItem.java:1187)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.ConfigItem.doUpdate(ConfigItem.java:542)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.UpdateEngine.processItem(UpdateEngine.java:210)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.UpdateEngine.updateTopLevelItem(UpdateEngine.java:165)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlAccessHandler.fillObjectModel(XmlAccessHandler.java:332)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlAccessHandler.endElement(XmlAccessHandler.java:210)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlUtils.parseSax(XmlUtils.java:295)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.Engine.forInputSourceSax(Engine.java:239)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.Engine.forInputSourceSax(Engine.java:174)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommand$2.run(XmlCommand.java:256)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommand$2.run(XmlCommand.java:251)
    at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommand.internalExecute(XmlCommand.java:267)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommand.execute(XmlCommand.java:184)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommandServlet.processInternal(XmlCommandServlet.java:238)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommandServlet.process(XmlCommandServlet.java:203)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommandServlet.doPost(XmlCommandServlet.java:150)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlAccessAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(XmlAccessAuthorizationFilter.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilterWithoutProjectID(ProjectIdFilter.java:405)
    at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilter(ProjectIdFilter.java:319)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.servletfilter.VirtualPortalServletFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalServletFilter.java:137)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommandException: EJPFB0002E: Exception occurred. [content-node Z6_00000000000000AU24LH4B1000 uniquename=ibm.portal.theme.simple.footer]
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentMappingData.updateUnrestricted(ContentMappingData.java:319)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentMappingData.access$000(ContentMappingData.java:76)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentMappingData$Action.run(ContentMappingData.java:654)
    at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentMappingData.executeUnrestricted(ContentMappingData.java:625)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.ibm.wps.contentmapping.exceptions.ContentMappingDataBackendExceptionImpl: com.ibm.wps.util.DataBackendException: EJQHL0007E: An exception occurred when trying to modify the page data in Web Content Management for the page with the ID [ObjectIDImpl 'Z6_00000000000000AU24LH4B1000', CONTENT_NODE, VP: 0, [Domain: rel], DB: 0000-000000000000000080F282D448560000]. Detailed Message: EJPFB0007E: Exception occurred : IBM Web Content Manager is not available.
    at com.ibm.wps.contentmapping.ContentMappingInfoControllerImpl.commit(ContentMappingInfoControllerImpl.java:227)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentMappingData.addContentMappings(ContentMappingData.java:501)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ContentMappingData.updateUnrestricted(ContentMappingData.java:315)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: com.ibm.wps.util.DataBackendException: EJQHL0007E: An exception occurred when trying to modify the page data in Web Content Management for the page with the ID [ObjectIDImpl 'Z6_00000000000000AU24LH4B1000', CONTENT_NODE, VP: 0, [Domain: rel], DB: 0000-000000000000000080F282D448560000]. Detailed Message: EJPFB0007E: Exception occurred : IBM Web Content Manager is not available.
    at com.ibm.wps.wcm.access.draft.WCMProjectHelperImpl.modifiedPage(WCMProjectHelperImpl.java:292)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.projects.ProjectHelperFilterAdapter.modifiedPage(ProjectHelperFilterAdapter.java:173)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.projects.ProjectHelperFilterAdapter.modifiedPage(ProjectHelperFilterAdapter.java:173)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.projects.ProjectHelperFilterAdapter.modifiedPage(ProjectHelperFilterAdapter.java:173)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.projects.ProjectHelperFilterChainImpl$2$1.call(ProjectHelperFilterChainImpl.java:430)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.wcm.SynchronizationEventControlServiceImpl.executeWithoutPortalUpdates(SynchronizationEventControlServiceImpl.java:69)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.projects.ProjectHelperFilterChainImpl$2.run(ProjectHelperFilterChainImpl.java:418)
    at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.projects.ProjectHelperFilterChainImpl.runUnrestricted(ProjectHelperFilterChainImpl.java:887)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.projects.ProjectHelperFilterChainImpl.modifiedPage(ProjectHelperFilterChainImpl.java:413)
    at com.ibm.wps.contentmapping.ContentMappingInfoControllerImpl.touchWCMPage(ContentMappingInfoControllerImpl.java:394)
    at com.ibm.wps.contentmapping.ContentMappingInfoControllerImpl.commit(ContentMappingInfoControllerImpl.java:224)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: com.ibm.wps.command.CommandException: EJPFB0007E: Exception occurred : IBM Web Content Manager is not available.
    at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:107)
    at com.ibm.wps.wcm.access.draft.WCMProjectHelperImpl.modifiedPage(WCMProjectHelperImpl.java:284)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.exceptions.ServiceNotAvailableException: IBM Web Content Manager is not available.
    at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.WCM_Repository.getWorkspace_aroundBody6(WCM_Repository.java:319)
    at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.WCM_Repository$AjcClosure7.run(WCM_Repository.java:1)
    at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect.ajc$around$com_ibm_workplace_wcm_api_WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect$1$77189ab8proceed(WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect.aj:1)
    at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect$WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect$1.run(WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect.aj:243)
    at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect.ajc$around$com_ibm_workplace_wcm_api_WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect$1$77189ab8(WCMAPIWorkspaceAspect.aj:294)
    at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.WCM_Repository.getWorkspace(WCM_Repository.java:294)
    at com.ibm.wps.wcm.access.draft.WCMProjectHelperImpl$2.run(WCMProjectHelperImpl.java:233)
    at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
    ... 90 more

]]></stacktrace>
    </status>
</request>
```

If I check the portal's SystemErr.log I actually find this error on startup, that seems related (ContentMapping stuff)

```
[8/4/17 10:04:16:009 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: The object or context contentmapping does not exist.; remaining name 'contentmapping/ContentMappingInfoHome'
[8/4/17 10:04:16:010 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:333)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:010 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:346)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:010 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.RootPortalJNDIContext.lookupObject(RootPortalJNDIContext.java:155)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:010 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:72)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:010 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:77)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:010 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:010 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.wcm.access.DependenciesImpl.getContentMappingInfoHome(DependenciesImpl.java:81)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.wcm.access.WCMHelperImpl.<init>(WCMHelperImpl.java:113)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.wcm.access.WCMHelperFactory.create(WCMHelperFactory.java:24)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wkplc.extensionregistry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:134)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.extreg.ExtensionsLookupContext.getExtensionInfo(ExtensionsLookupContext.java:249)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.extreg.ExtensionsLookupContext.getExtension(ExtensionsLookupContext.java:148)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.extreg.ExtensionsLookupContext.lookupInternal(ExtensionsLookupContext.java:410)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.extreg.ExtensionsLookupContext.lookup(ExtensionsLookupContext.java:381)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:346)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:011 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.RootPortalJNDIContext.lookupObject(RootPortalJNDIContext.java:155)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:72)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:77)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.model.command.CommandInstantiatorDependencies.<init>(CommandInstantiatorDependencies.java:54)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.model.command.DefaultCommandInstantiators.<init>(DefaultCommandInstantiators.java:58)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.model.command.DefaultCommandInstantiators.<init>(DefaultCommandInstantiators.java:54)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wkplc.extensionregistry.ConfigurationElement.getExecutable(ConfigurationElement.java:214)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:012 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wkplc.extensionregistry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:124)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.model.command.CommandFactoryImpl.addExtension(CommandFactoryImpl.java:197)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.model.command.CommandFactoryImpl.initExtensions(CommandFactoryImpl.java:440)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.model.command.CommandFactoryImpl.<init>(CommandFactoryImpl.java:149)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.model.command.CommandFactoryHomeImpl.<init>(CommandFactoryHomeImpl.java:64)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.model.command.service.CommandFactoryBootstrapService.init(CommandFactoryBootstrapService.java:95)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.Service.init(Service.java:101)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.Service.init(Service.java:78)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.ServiceManager.createService(ServiceManager.java:362)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.ServiceManager.initInternal(ServiceManager.java:261)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.ServiceManager.init(ServiceManager.java:173)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.services.ServiceManager.init(ServiceManager.java:115)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:013 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.init(Servlet.java:986)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1376)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:662)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:628)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:453)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:014 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1246)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1514)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:704)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1096)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:798)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2314)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:015 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5489)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5615)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2319)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
[8/4/17 10:04:16:016 CEST] 00000076 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: you need to look and see why wcm is not loading, if the errors about the user are related, then it could be that it is having problems related to user store

Comment: There's a technote here for Portal 8.0 CF15: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21960636 . You can check if that solution works for you. During normal use of the Portal profile, do you see any problems accessing WCM content?